# Sending Data over 2.1 MB fails for WCF

Tags: wcf, serialization, wcf-binding

i am writing a code which will upload selected files to some server using WCF.
i am using .Net 4.0.
I am having one aspx page with fileupload control.
where user browse the file and click save i am keeping these files (read in byte then converted to base64) in session object.
there is one more button called Upload.
when i clicked on upload i am calling WCF service and passing object from session.
following is my binding config from client side

```
<i>   
<bindings>
<wsHttpBinding>
<binding name="WSHttpBinding_DefaultService" closeTimeout="00:20:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
             transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00" enabled="false" />
       <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</i>
```

and following one from Server

```
<i>
<wsHttpBinding>
<binding name="WSHttpBinding_DefaultService" closeTimeout="0:20:00"
  openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00"
  bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
  messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
  allowCookies="false">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
  <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00"
    enabled="false" />
  <security mode="Message">
    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
      algorithmSuite="Default" />
  </security>
</binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
</i>
```

also i made chages to httpruntime

```
<i> <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"  executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="2097151"/></i>
```

issue is whenever i try to select multiple files with total size greater than 2.5 MB my object is not getting transported to WCF it's throwing error

```
<i>The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. >>>> The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. >>>> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. >>>> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host >>>>     </i>
```

so what i need to do?
i am trying to find solution with wsHttpBinding
so any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In your httpRuntime configuration, the property `maxRequestLength="2097151"` indicates a max request size of about 2.1 MB.  Increasing that should increase your maximum file size.

For larger files, you may want to create some kind of [streaming implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx), so you don't need to be limited by the maxRequestLength property.